# Read-only filegroups in sql server

Tags: sql-server

how to check whether the filegroups is in read-only mode or read-write mode ? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this (sql server 2005+):

```
SELECT name, is_read_only FROM sys.filegroups
```

or this (sql 2000):

```
SELECT groupname, CAST(Status & 0x8 as BIT) Is_ReadOnly FROM sysfilegroups
```

Answer (score 2):

[sys.filegroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187782.aspx)

```
SELECT name, type, is_read_only 
FROM sys.filegroups
```

Or [FILEPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188401.aspx) / [FILEGROUPPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188069.aspx) to test specific ones